# How to make custom Dynamic homepage in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created my a custom template now what ever I do the home page skips the actual dynamic content and read the static BlOG text given from the admin Panel ?
 This is what I did so far :

First I created this `home.php` file :

```
<?php

/*
    Template Name: Home Homepage
*/

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container pull-left">
                <div class="row-fluid" id="">
                    <ul>
                    <div class="span2">
                        <a href="<?php echo $myurls;?>/read" ><i><img id="read"  src="<?php echo $myurls;?>images/buttons/readbtn.png" alt="read"> </i></a>

                    </div>                  
                    <div class="span2">

                        <a href="<?php echo $myurls;?>/watch"><i><img id="watch"  src="<?php echo $myurls;?>images/buttons/watchbtn.png" alt="watch"> </i></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="span2">

                        <a href="<?php echo $myurls;?>/view"><i><img id="view" src="<?php echo $myurls;?>images/buttons/viewbtn.png" alt="view"> </i></a>
                    </div>
                     <div class="span2">

                        <a href="<?php echo $myurls;?>/listen"><i><img id="listen" src="<?php echo $myurls;?>images/buttons/listenbtn.png" alt="listen"> </i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </ul>
</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Secondly I created a page on Admin Panel using this template.
Then I set in the Readings section>Settings I chose Home

Now it doesn't take the content I provided, it only takes the STATIC text from the Admin Panel!

Comment: We need more info than that. Possibly more description of what you want, or some actual code would be helpful.

Comment: @mdance Thanks I added more info!

Comment: There's also a wordpress site on stackoverflow that may be of use to you. It was for me a long time ago. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jonnny, Thanks, but I don't have any credits there! So I thought here someone would actually help! It's disappointing that most of the time I end up spending 2 days solving it myself!

Comment: When you write a clear and concise question, and not complain in comments about how you haven't received your free help, you are much more likely to get a satisfactory answer.  Also see:  http://sscce.org

Comment: can I know why people vote down the question ? is it too obvious :/ ?

Comment: There is nothing personal about this.  I simply gave you two important tips for obtaining good help along with a link that guides you about how to write better questions.  You'll get more out of this site if you follow these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I didn't have any luck to get an answer and I have been told to watch my manners on StackOverFlow (points taken) , here is my Solution:

In my scenario that I wanted to create a CUSTOM Dynamic Home Page that will contain my own PHP code, the following steps helped :

1- First this is what my File Hierarchy looks like :

[image: file Hir]

2- All the other Tutorials that I found on Google say :

- Choose Front Page to Home [example](http://www.simplethemes.com/tutorials/help/home-page-setup)
- Or create home.php [example 2](http://chriscarvache.com/2009-02/wordpress/wordpress-cms-dynamic-homepage/)
  Neither of them Worked!
  FORGET ABOUT That do the following :

Let this be as the way it is :
[image: setting image]

Then Go to the `front-page.php` , if it doesn't exist create one and Include your `PHP code` there.

Hope this help the tons of other people trying to do the same!...

Cheers,